# How to determine if currency symbol is to the left or right of a number on MacOS

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-foundation

How do I determine if the currency symbol is supposed to be on the left or right of a number using CFLocale / CFNumberFormatter in a Mac Carbon project?

I need to interface with a spreadsheet application which requires me to pass a number, currency symbol, currency symbol location and padding instead of a CStringRef created with CFNumberFormatter.

```
CFLocaleRef currentLocale = CFLocaleCopyCurrent();
CFTypeRef currencySymbol = CFLocaleGetValue (currentLocale, kCFLocaleCurrencySymbol);
```

provides me with the currency symbol as a string. But I'm lost on how to determine the position of the currency symbol...

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, I have started to create a string representing a currency value and determining the position of the currency symbol by searching the string, but this sure looks fishy to me.

```
    CFNumberFormatterRef numberFormatter = CFNumberFormatterCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFLocaleCopyCurrent(), kCFNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle);
    double someNumber = 0;
    CFStringRef asString = CFNumberFormatterCreateStringWithValue(kCFAllocatorDefault, numberFormatter, kCFNumberDoubleType, &someNumber);
```

...

Feel free to hit me with a rolled-up newspaper and tell me the real answer...

Answer (score 0):

You could try inspecting the format string returned from `CFNumberFormatterGetFormat`. It [looks like](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Number_Format_Patterns) you want to search for `¤` which is `\u00A4`.